# Need to simulate keypress jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that uses the value of a textbox (prodinput) to hide/show links in a dropdown list. It works when a user types in a string manually but when I want to auto-populate the value by passing a url parameter I'll need to trigger a keyup or keydown to get it to call the function.

Here is the function that does the search (located in the core.js):

```
prodinput.on('keyup, keydown',function() {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.support-product .browse-products a').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(search) > -1) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the function I'm using to trigger the function above (located on the page I'm trying to run it on.

```
$(function(){
                $target = $('.browse-products .display');
                $target.val($trimmed);
                $('.browse-products').addClass('active');
                $target.focus();
                var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown" );
                $target.trigger(e);
            });
```

I've tried using:

```
$target.keyup();
```

and as shown above:

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown" );
$target.trigger(e);
```

I'm wondering if it's a problem with the order in which things load on the page.

Comment: Why not make it a named function and... call it?

Comment: OR `$(function() { $("#prodinput").on('keyup, keydown',function() {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.support-product .browse-products a').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(search) > -1) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
}).keyup()
});`

Answer (score -1):

I'd put your keyup code in a named function.

```
$(function () {
    myFunction();
    prodinput.on('keyup, keydown', function () {
        myFunction();
    })
};

var myFunction = function () {
    var search = $('#prodinput').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.support-product .browse-products a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(search) > -1) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't need to support ancient browsers you can just listen for the `input` event which covers keypress and change events. Then after attaching the listener simply trigger the event:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#prodinput").on('input', function() {//alternatively you could use change and keyup
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.support-product .browse-products a').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(search) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().show();
      } else {
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
    });
  }).trigger("input");//trigger the event now
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="prodinput" value="peanuts" />
<div class="support-product">
  <ul class="browse-products">
    <li><a href="#">jam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">elephants</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">peanuts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to give some feedback? Perhaps this doesn't work for you? Maybe you feel that I've misunderstood the requirement or that my approach is flawed? Just down-voting serves no useful purpose unless you back it up with reasoning.